# Difference between /etc/passwd and /etc/passwd- in linux

Tags: linux

I was asked what the difference is between `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/passwd-` but have not been able to find anything.  Can someone please help me understand what the difference is?

Comment: What is `-passwd`?

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. Can you explain what is it `-passwd` and what it does? Please [edit] your post and maybe add a reference where you read about it... for the ones that read you the 1st time it can be difficult to understand what you mean. [ask]

Comment: actually one of my senior asked me the question

Comment: what is the difference between passwd and -passwd(hyphen)

Comment: sorry its passwd-

Answer (score 1):

Ah, now I see your question.  You are not asking about a command `passwd-` you are asking about the file `/etc/passwd-`.  That is a backup of the `/etc/passwd` file.  You can see so in the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man5/passwd.5.html)

> /etc/passwd-
>             Backup file for /etc/passwd.
>
> ```
>       Note that this file is used by the tools of the shadow toolsuite,
>       but not by all user and password management tools.
> ```

This question has also been asked at the [U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27717/who-creates-etc-group-gshadow-passwd-shadow) Stack Exchange site.